# implementing Brute Force in c++

Tags: c++, brute-force, array-algorithms

I have a problem that deals with optimization of a game that includes 2 players.
So we have an undirected connected graph with a number of edges and some vertices.
Each player has to remove edges and if a vertex is isolated his score increases by
one and then you have to remove another edge. The graph is represented in a so-called
"adjacency matrix".For each one in the array there is a connection between two vertices  For example, in case we have a triangle, we have the following array:

0 1 1 first row

1 0 1 second row

1 1 0 third row

the rows correspond with the vertices and the columns correspond with its possible connections to other vertices. We are assigned to use a recursive function to apply
Brute Force. I have put a lot of thought into writing the code for this function. I 
implemented some code and compiled and ran it. I have absolutely no idea why it doesn't
function. My code for this function:

```
   class Matrix {
        public:
    int berekenZet (bool** array, bool player);
    int berekenScore (bool** array, int rij, int kolom);
    bool checkRij (bool** array, int rij);
    void setGetal (int nummer) {getal = nummer;};
    Matrix ();



private:
    int getal;


    int maxScoreA;
    int huidigScore;
    int maxverschil;
    int maxScoreB;
    int tellerHuidig;
```

Matrix::Matrix() {

```
  huidigScore = 0;
maxScoreA = 0;
maxScoreB = 0;
```

}

```
 bool Matrix::checkRij (bool** array, int rij) {


            for (int i=0; i<getal; i++) {
    if (array[rij][i] == true)
        return false;
  }
  return true;
```

}

```
    int Matrix::berekenScore (bool** Array, int rij, int kolom) {
if (checkRij (Array, rij) == true )
    huidigScore ++;
if (checkRij (Array, kolom) == true) 
    huidigScore ++;
return huidigScore;
```

}

```
  int Matrix::berekenZet (bool** array, bool player) {
  int score = 0;
  int bestescore = -5;
  int slechtstescore = 5;
  int something;
  something = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < getal; i++){
  for(int j = i + 1; j <getal; j++){
  huidigScore = 0;

  if(array[i][j]){
    something++;
    array[i][j] = false;
    array[j][i] = false;
    score = 0;
    if(player == true){
      score = score + berekenScore(array, i ,j ); 
      }
    else{
      score = score - berekenScore(array, i, j);
      }
      cout << "player" << player << endl;
      cout << "score" << score << endl;


    if(huidigScore == 0)
      score = score + berekenZet(array, !player);
    else
      score = score + berekenZet(array, player);


    if(player == true && score > bestescore)
      bestescore = score; 
    else if(player == false && score < slechtstescore)
      slechtstescore = score;



      array[i][j] == true;
      array[j][i] == true;

  } //if
}//for
}//for 


if(player == true && something != 0){
cout << "bestescore" << bestescore << endl;
return bestescore;
}//  if outside of double for loop
else if(player == false && something != 0){
cout << "slechtstescore" << slechtstescore << endl;
return slechtstescore;
} // else if outside of double for loop  

else if(something = 0){
cout << "bestescore" << bestescore << endl;         
return 0;

}  // determine whether array was empty when function was called
```

bestescore and slechtstescore are dutch for best and worstscore.
berekenScore adjusts the number of points earned after an edge
is removed and saves it in huidigScore. So basically 0, 1 or 2.

I call this function in the int main:

```
cout << "Aantal takken: " << takken << endl;

a = matrix.berekenZet(Array, player);
```

I ran it using the following adjacency matrix:

5

0 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0

It outputs "score" just 5 times, so it seems to be ignoring the for loops in the function,
also bestescore is once set to some million value and is then set to 5. I'm not a
very experienced programmer so I might just be missing over something..??

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you only have 5 edges and thus score is output just five times. The nested loop

> for(int i = 0; i < getal; i++)
>     for(int j = i + 1; j < getal; j++)

iterates over all the possible edges and the conditions if(array[i][j]) filters out the true edges so the loop will only execute |E| times.

Also, in the loop you set

> ```
> array[i][j] = false;
> array[j][i] = false;
> ```

and then

> ```
> array[i][j] == true;
> array[j][i] == true;
> ```

and thus only one edge is removed at a time. You probably want one more loop that removes multiple edges at the time to get the brute force implementation.

Edit: You don't seem to be resetting huidigScore at every call. I would recommend to change your helper functions as follows:

> ```
> int Matrix::berekenScore (bool** Array, int rij, int kolom) 
> {
> int huidigScore = 0; 
> if (checkRij (Array, rij) == true )
>   huidigScore ++; 
> if (checkRij (Array, kolom) == true) 
>   huidigScore ++; 
> return huidigScore;
> }
> ```

The above function has huidigScore as private variable. Now, instead of the following code snippet:

> ```
> if(player == true){
>   score = score + berekenScore(array, i ,j ); 
>   }
> else{
>   score = score - berekenScore(array, i, j);
>   }
>   cout << "player" << player << endl;
>   cout << "score" << score << endl;
> ```

you can have

> ```
> int huidigScore = berekenScore(array, i ,j )
> if(player == true){
>   score = score + huidigScore; 
>   }
> else{
>   score = score - huidigScore;
>   }
>   cout << "player" << player << endl;
>   cout << "score" << score << endl;
> ```

General advice: Avoid using public variables if you can. They complicate reasoning and debugging of programs.

Comment: Oke thanks for your responde, I understand your explanation, but then still I don't understand why it outputs "score" only 5 times since

Comment: ke thanks a lot for your responde, I understand your explanation, but then still I don't understand why it outputs "score" only 5 times since each function has a double for loop. I understand it skips all the false array elements because of the if(array[i][j]) condition. I figured that in the fifth function call the lasting 2 array elements should be set to false. But  then   the aray = true; statements should assure that when a value is returned to the previous function it can remove these array elements in the  fourth function preceding to the last.. I don't know

Comment: Excuse me for the inconvenience, I have posted the rest of the code in the original question. This includes berekenScore and checkRij, which is included in berekenScore

Comment: Ok. I see one immediate problem. You don't seem to reset the global variable huidigScore. I would recommend you to instead have huidigScore as a parameter (pass it by reference) to berekenScore which sets it to zero at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Oke I have a class including huidigScore in private and all three functions: berekenScore berekenZet en checkRij. I will update my original question with the class-code. But there could indeed be something wrong with huidigScore. How do you suggest I pass huidigScore by reference to berekenScore? Shall i just initialize huidigScore in berekenZet, set it to 0 and then pass it by reference to berekenScore?

Comment: Check out my answer with the new edits. Hopefully that will fix your problem. Good luck :).